# How to get data from mongoDB based on date from express.?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, timestamp, isodate

I am trying to get data from mongoDB collection based on the date it is created.

> **Date format using to get data:**  yyyy-mm-dd (eg: 2015-04-14)
>
> **Format saved in collection** : timestamp: "2015-04-13T17:50:48.761Z"

Controller :

```
       $scope.getExpences = function (date) {
            SelectedMemberExpence.get( date )
                .success(function (result) {
                    $scope.allExpences = result;
                })
        }
```

Service :

```
.service('SelectedTimeExpence', function ($http) {
    return {
      get : function(datetime) {
      return $http.get('/api/expences/'+ datetime); 
    },
      delete : function(datetime) {
      return $http.delete('/api/expences/'+ datetime);
    }
   }
})
```

Express code :

```
router
  .param('datetime', function (req, res, next) {
     req.dbQuery = { timestamp : req.params.datetime };
     next();
  })
  .route('/expences/:datetime')
     .get(function (req, res) {
        var collection = db.get('memberExpences');
        collection.find(req.dbQuery , function (err, data) {
            res.json(data);
        });
});
```

I know, I am doing something wrong in 'express' code function. Please help anyone to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timestamp` field in your collection is of string type which resembles an ISO date timestamp string. The query will certainly not work because you will be comparing two completely different strings (based on length, the `timestamp` field has more characters than the `datetime` req parameter value).

Would be much easier if you were to include another field in your document schema that actually represents a date:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function (doc){
    doc.created_on = ISODate(doc.timestamp);
    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

You can then use a range query to search for documents whose value for the `created_on` field is greater than a Date object representing the start of the `datetime` variable day, and less than a Date object representing the `datetime` variable day end.

First you need to construct the Date objects representing the start and end of the `datetime` day. For example:

```js
var datetime = "2015-04-14",
start = new Date(datetime),
dateParts = datetime.split('-'),
y = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10),
m = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10),
d = parseInt(dateParts[2], 10),
end = new Date(y, m-1, d+1);
console.log(start.toISOString()); // "2015-04-14T00:00:00.000Z "
console.log(end.toISOString());  // "2015-04-15T00:00:00.000Z"
```

In your Express code you can then modify it to reflect the above:

```
router
  .param('datetime', function (req, res, next) {
      var start = new Date(req.params.datetime),
          dateParts = datetime.split('-'),
          y = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10),
          m = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10),
          d = parseInt(dateParts[2], 10),
          end = new Date(y, m-1, d+1);  
      req.dbQuery = {"created_on": { $gte: start, $lt: end }};
      next();
  })
  .route('/expences/:datetime')
     .get(function (req, res) {
        var collection = db.get('memberExpences');
        collection.find(req.dbQuery , function (err, data) {
            res.json(data);
        });
});
```

Note the use of the special **`$`** operators, **`$gte`** (greater-than-or-equal) and **`$lt`** (less-than), which are used to perform a range query to get the matching documents.

Using **[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)**:

```
var start = moment("2015-04-14").format();
var end = moment(start).add('days', 1);
db.collection.find({"created_on": {"$gte": start, "$lt": end}});
```

**EDIT**

In node, the Mongo driver will give you an ISO string, not the object thus if you want to include an additional `created_on` field in your document, simply add a new field with the current date value. For example:

```
.post(function (req, res) { 
     var date = new Date(); 
     var expence = req.body; 
     expence["created_on"] = date;
     var collection = db.get('memberExpences'); 
     collection.insert(expence, function (err, data) { 
         res.json(200); 
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I understood everything, just didn't understand how to create 'created_on' field. Since I am generating using this function -------  .post(function (req, res) {
     var date = new Date();
     var expence = req.body;
     expence.timestamp = date;
     var collection = db.get('memberExpences');
     collection.insert(expence, function (err, data) {
      res.json(200);
     })
   });--------- How to insert date in 'created_on' field

Comment: @anonymousrajat Thanks. I've just updated my answer to address your other question. I've also realised that the string you are getting from the timestamp field in node is an ISO string, not the ISODate object but if you query in Mongo shell it will show you the type as ISODate. So, the way you were creating the timestamp field is the correct way, just that in the mongo driver it's represented as an ISO string.

Comment: It worked. Thanks @chridam. But i have one question, why there is -1 with 'm' in end = new Date(y, m-1, d+1). d+1 is fine but y m-1

Comment: It's because with [**JavaScript**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp), when creating a Date object, months are zero based, and days aren't.

Answer (score 0):

A little change I had to use with the above answer that I want to share with you

```
var start = moment("2020-04-14").format();
db.collection.find({"created_on": {"$gte": new Date(start)}});
```